# Included files from standard directories can silently replace existing macros?

Tags: c++, preprocessor

Create the file `/usr/local/include/define_x.h` with the single line:

```
#define X "/usr/local/include"
```

The following program `foo.cpp` compiles and runs fine with no warnings:

```
#include <iostream>

#define X "local"
#include <define_x.h>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "X = " << X << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output: `X = /usr/local/include`

Now swap lines 3 and 4:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <define_x.h>
#define X "local"

int main()
{
  std::cout << "X = " << X << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Now the output is `X = local` as expected, but now there is a compiler warning:

```
foo.cpp:4: warning: "X" redefined
 #define X "local"

In file included from foo.cpp:3:
/usr/local/include/define_x.h:1: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define X "/usr/local/include"
```

#### Question: Why is there is no warning in the first version?

Both were compiled with gcc 8.2.1: `g++ foo.cpp`.

It seems it has something to do with placing files in the standard /usr/include or /usr/local/include directories, as placing them either in the current directory or another found via `-I` doesn't produce this effect.

Comment: just a wild guess: is it possible that your compiler options have a `-isystem` ? That could explain why there is no warning generated depending on from where the file is included

Comment: ups sorry missed the `g++ foo.cpp` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[System header files](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html) often cannot be written in strictly conforming C. They may change some preprocessor macros several times like is this example:

```
#define FOO 0
#ifdef BAR
#define FOO 1
#endif
```

It would be annoying to have a warning for all these changes. Therefore the warning is not issued for system header files.

Your code line

```
#include <define_x.h>
```

declares the header file to a [system header file](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html). You should get a different result if you use

```
#include "define_x.h"
```

Comment: *You should get a different result if you use ...* - I tried that and I don't. Do you?

Comment: From your first link: "The header files declaring interfaces to the operating system and runtime libraries often cannot be written in strictly conforming C. Therefore, GCC gives code found in system headers special treatment." - Thank you, that is the information I was looking for.